# Работа с MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Если я использую класс для работы с БД, я создаю новый объект этого класса, из которого вызываю функцию для выполнения запроса, я подключаюсь к БД, выполняю запрос, выполняю закрытие подключения.
Обрабатываю данные, вывожу на страницу.

По идее - скрипт отработал и исчез.

При повторном запросе с полученной страницы - опять повторять те же самые действия? Или что-то можно сохранить в сессию, чтобы не пересоздавать объект?

Хочется увидеть пример (схему) описанных мною действий в правильном виде.

На разных сайтах пишут по разному, в комментариях много мнений "за" и "против" и не совсем понятно, что из всего правильно, а что нет.

Comment: Ну, сохранять в сессию то конечно можно, но если нужно. Если это небольшой массив информации, который часто используется и мало подвержен изменению, будь то всевозможные айди, настройки клиентские, права, и прочее, то можно. Либо записать в объект и сериализовывать/десериализовывать. В принципе, суть та же, но как грится, сбоку.

Answer (score 1):

> подключаюсь к БД, выполняю запрос, выполняю закрытие подключения.

Немного не так. подключение происходит строго 1 раз, закрытие вообще не нужно

> При повторном запросе с полученной страницы - опять повторять те же самые действия?

Да.

> Или что-то можно сохранить в сессию, чтобы не пересоздавать объект?

Нет.

> Хочется увидеть пример (схему) описанных мною действий в правильном виде.

- создаешь объект класса. При этом происходит подключение к БД.
- выполняешь запрос
- выполняешь запрос
- выполняешь запрос
- обрабатываешь данные, выводишь на страницу

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду, закрываю подключение после выполнения всех запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить соеденение, для второго подключения, в PHP не получится и это не нужно. 
Правильнее сохранять полученые данные не в сессию, а в кэш. Если данные писать в сессию, то они будут доступны только одному пользователю.

Нужно после отработанного запроса записать сериализованные полученные данные в redis, memcached ну или в файл, с каким нибудь именем и при втором запросе сначала посмотреть в кэше, а потом уже лезть в БД.

- Спросить кэш, если данные есть в нём и они не устарели, то взять данные из кэша.
- Если данные не взялись из кэша то подключение к БД, запрос.
- После запроса сериализация и запись результата в кэш.
- Закрытие соеденения.

Comment: Тут нужно учитывать что в MySQL есть собственный кэш последних запросов, и использовать кэш уровнем выше - на ваше усмотрение.